# Can we clean up the footer?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, footer

The footer for graduated sites is a mess! Meta and Area 51 are stuck in the middle of the list of graduated sites, since it lists sites in order of creation.

**Updated proposal with better category names**:
[image: Splits sites by general category]

This way, sites are logically arranged instead of in chronological order (after all, chronology being unlogical is why we have the voting system, isn't it?). Better yet, with this re-organization, we can make it easier to find the right site for our questions.

Comment: I've been thinking something needed to be done with but wasn't sure what.  Great mock up

Comment: I'm gonna go with "what's wrong with the footer?"

Comment: I know my "Topics" is essentially "Misc", as any other replacement would be too, but I avoided the exact label "Misc" as it sometimes implies lesser importance or significance.

Comment: @drac Try finding a specific site that you don't visit often through the current footer. Now look for that site in my image with the category names to help you. Which is faster?

Comment: @waiwai933 ~ If it's a site that I don't visit often then it doesn't really matter does it?

Comment: @drac My point isn't that it's a site you don't visit often. I'm just trying to remove the existing bias since you might know where all your current favorite sites are.

Comment: @waiwai933 the example you provide is an answer looking for a question

Comment: @drac Let me try to rephrase this. SE is about logical sorting, which is why answers are sorted by default by votes and not by time. So why shouldn't we do the same about the footer?

Comment: Gaming really needs to be in a better category than in "Computers".

Comment: And ServerFault needs to be in a better category than "Developers" :).

Comment: Since when does $\tex$ have to do with numbers?

Answer (score 13):

**Posers:** [stackoverflow] [gamedev] [webmasters] [serverfault]
**Haters:** [superuser] [askubuntu] [webapps]
**Lunatics:** [gaming] [math] [cooking] [photography]
**Ingrates:** [meta] [area 51] [careers] [api/apps]

Comment: With apologies to Roger Pate... :-D

Comment: Please sir, may I have another?

Comment: No, this will never do. I'm both a hater _and_ a poser but I only ever hang out on Stack Overflow unless I'm heckling Joel Spolsky into giving me a 100K+ job without an interview on Programmers. I feel excluded. (Well I guess I hang out every now and then on Meta but I'm not an Ingrate)

Answer (score 7):

Were going to roll out a new footer next week across all sites, including beta sites which will separate the list into categories, vertically.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Ooh, I love sticky notes in footers!

Comment: Shouldn't "Other" be "Stack Exchange" (or something) to indicate that they are all sites related to the network rather than sites not otherwise categorised?

Comment: Nonsense! Meta Stack Overflow is LIFE!

Comment: Nice, I see it's live now. Time to tag this question [meta-tag:status-completed]. :)

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer a just alphabetic order. You don't need to know what categories exist, and in which order the topics were added to SE.

Answer (score -1):

**Developers:** [stackoverflow] [gamedev] [webmasters] [serverfault]
**Computers:** [superuser] [askubuntu] [webapps]
**Topics:** [gaming] [math] [cooking] [photography]
**Stack Exchange:** [meta] [area 51] [careers] [api/apps]

Comment: Server Fault in "developers" seems off, but I'm not sure.

Comment: IT - Computers - Topics - SE?

Comment: @VxJ: I don't like IT much here, but I can't really say why.  Perhaps it's just too broad and not a label users of those sites apply to themselves often.  Obviously "Topics" isn't either, but "Computer users" (also a bit too broad) and "SE users" are.

Comment: s/IT/Pattern of Lights Managers/
?
(See <http://xkcd.com/722/> )

Also perhaps, Light Pattern Organizers, or keyboard monkeys.

Comment: Computer Science doesn't extend to Administration properly, and IT doesn't extend to Development properly. What is the middle ground?