# Customize the bottom of the page with selected stack exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, footer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we change the way the links on the bottom of SE are ordered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116737/can-we-change-the-way-the-links-on-the-bottom-of-se-are-ordered)

The sites of stack exchange are too many now, and I wish if there is somehow a customize option to select what I like more to see them on my bottom page and go to them fast and easy.

I like to make a round look of the sites that they interesting me and see whats new, whats up etc. I know that I get the message that I need, but after if not have messages and the days go by, I forget them.

Now I start with stack overflow and on bottom there only two tree that I am interesting most, and one two others not exist, and I need to search on book marks to find them again, or on area 51.

**The automatic way** : To find for every user the best score on all sites and place them on bottom by this order.

**The manual way**: To let us choose what sites to see on the bottom page.

Of course I like to also have some suggestions as they are now together with my manual select.

My opinion is that custom links on bottom of the page can give a boost to the site with less daily interesting like so.

Comment: Related: [Can we clean up the footer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69025)

Comment: @TimStone To tell you the truth, I have forget one site after some weeks :) If there was on the bottom, that I am looking at it, I never have this issue. I use the bottom to navigate from site to site.

Comment: @Aristos: Do you mean beta sites? Because those aren't listed on fully launched sites, and fully launched sites aren't listed on beta sites. Two separate lists.

Comment: @animuson Yes beta too, This questions are similar but not the same proposal.

Comment: @PopularDemand I look it, I think that is not the same proposal (or I did not understand it) I propose here to have our custom selection list. (change per user)

Comment: I never said it was the same proposal. In fact, I intentionally avoided the word "duplicate" because it is not the same proposal. I just thought it was relevant, since both posts are about footer organization.

Comment: @PopularDemand Yes I notice that ! it is relative

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, so I won't post it as one. But... If you click on the "Stack Exchange" logo at the top-left, then click on the "All Sites" tab, you'll see a list of all the Stack Exchange sites, ordered by your reputation (and presumably, interest/participation) on each of them. Much more convenient than scrolling all the way down to the bottom of the page, *and* already sorted for you.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes I have found that :) on top of the page, but is not show correct the sites that I have participate. Show only 3, I am also on other five that is not on the correct order, in one of them I have 208 rep and now show in on top (maybe is somewhere there but I can not locate it).