# Make sites that I am a member of more prominent in the footer

Tags: feature-request, linked-accounts, footer

Now that [this footer cleanup request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69025/can-we-clean-up-the-footer) has been implemented and the links to other sites are in columns, I find myself struggling to find links to sites that I am already a member of.

For example, I like to read the questions over at [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), so I have an account there. To get there from Stack Overflow, I have to either expand the more links in the footer and locate it within there, (a challenge in itself, why no search?). Or I can go to my profile, but that only displays my top 5 accounts so I have to click a More link there too.

Can we maybe sort them so that the ones I am a member of are at the top? Or create a separate column entirely like "My Sites"?

Comment: There is another way: The "all sites" section in the MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ lists the sites you're a member of first, before the other sites.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ah nicely spotted, thank you.